# Fast algorithm to find keywords in an HTML page using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, search, dictionary

I have a JS specialty dictionary that find certain keywords on a page and add explanatory tooltips to them. Right now I'm using RegEx to find the keywords, but I suspect it will get slow very soon, when my dictionary grows bigger. I store dictionary entries in an array so I think that can be improved as well. My site language is Vietnamese and my keywords will all be English.

Any idea on improving performance will be much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could process your dictionary server side (checks output against keywords), then add a handler to each matched item (a class or other html element to identify the definition to use..). then use javascript to bind each element to your dictionary. This way your server is doing the heavy lifting.

1) Server loads your dictionary file and compares against text you are about to output

2) Where a match is found add

```
<span class="definition">yourword</span>
```

3) Generic javascript event handler (this is written in jQuery but of course you can fdo it anyway you like)

```
$('.definition').mouseOver(function(){
    var keyword = $(this).html();
    //load your definition using the keyword...
})
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I thought about moving the operation to server side, but my server isn't very fast and I want to be able to use this dictionary on some other sites that I dont have access to the source code as well.

Comment: O.K - but no matter how slow your server is, it's going to be faster than your users browser. However I don't know your traffic level which would be the deal breaker - if you have high traffic and a slow server then not doing this processing server side is maybe the best thing to do. Also depends on the size of your page :-)

Answer (score 0):

See my answer to a related question: [javascript: find strings in dom and emphasize it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1972515/javascript-find-strings-in-dom-and-emphasize-it/1972664#1972664)

Also see the accepted answer to that question which is a jQuery plugin to do just what you want.

The problem with doing this with regexp is not speed since some people claim that the DOM parsing method can actually be slower. The problem is avoiding crazy corner casses like: you don't want to replace a javascript string that happens to contain the keyword, you don't want to replace css class name or id that happens to contain the keyword, etc.

In my experience, the DOM way is fast enough. In fact, my website has a list of more than 100 keywords and it manages to install tooltips on all of them in under half a second (certainly faster than my eye can see).

Comment: Your eye can differentiate between ~40ms. :)

Comment: I see what you're getting at. Actually what I do is go to certain nodes and regex there, I dont regex the whole BODY node... Your advise on avoiding some nodes is definitely helpful, thanks. I expect my dictionary to contain a thousand words soon, though. Would the javascript hang the browser or would it run in the background slowly. I dont really need the keywords to be processed right away, I just dont want it slowing down the page load.